excluding node_modules on esbuild for aws lmabda deployment
I am using Lambda Layers with my Lambda functions to host my dependencies. In my case, the lambda layer contains my entire node_modules.
The primary reason for doing this is to make each lambda package smaller.
I just have one confusion. Is it okay to exclude the entire 'node_modules' directory in my esbuild.js file?
For now, this my esbuild.js file:
const esbuild = require('esbuild');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const handlersDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/handlers');
const distDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

if (!fs.existsSync(distDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(distDir);
}

// Get all handler files
const handlerFiles = fs.readdirSync(handlersDir).filter(file => 
file.endsWith('.ts'));

handlerFiles.forEach(file => {
  const entryPoint = path.join(handlersDir, file);
  const outFile = path.join(distDir, file.replace('.ts', '.js'));

  esbuild.buildSync({
      entryPoints: [entryPoint],
      bundle: true,
      platform: 'node',
      target: 'node20',
      outfile: outFile,
      external: ['aws-sdk', '@revistal/pronx'], 
      // ==> why can't i just use 'node_modules' and exclude it altogether because 
      // node_modules is in my Lambda Layer? <==
 });

console.log(`Built ${file} to ${outFile}`);
});

As you can see, currently I am excluding only two libraries, but I am thinking now that even though these library are already in the Lambda Layer, why am I explicitly excluding these libraries. I can just exclude the entire node_modules. Does make sense?
I tried to exclude my node_modules folder, but when I build the my lambdas, each lambda function turns into a massive, like 10,000 lines per lambda function.
But if I exclude this: external: ['aws-sdk', '@revistal/pronx'], I get a normal lambda function, probably 200 some lines.
